# How to add dynamic filename to the file which is getting unloaded from redshift unload query with a partition by column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

`CREATE temp table temp_table ( id INT, name VARCHAR(50), age INT, city VARCHAR(50) ); INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (1, 'John', 25, 'New York'), (2, 'Jane', 30, 'Los Angeles'), (3, 'Bob', 28, 'Chicago'), (4, 'Alice', 22, 'San Francisco'); UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM temp_table') TO 's3://<s3 bucket>/folder_1/' IAM_ROLE '<aws credentials>' ALLOWOVERWRITE PARALLEL OFF DELIMITER as ',' ADDQUOTES header PARTITION BY (city);`

The file name which is generated in each of the folders is 000 Is there a way to change the filename based on the columns for eg "newyork_000", "losangeles_000" directly in this unload query?

Answer (score 0):

I think clearing up what S3 is and isn't will help here.  S3 is an object store which in part means that there are just 2 pieces of information needed to locate any object/file.  Those are the bucket-name and object-key.  In your example these are "" and "folder_1/city=newyork/000".  These 2 strings are the coordinates of the file.  At the base level of s3 there are no folders.  (I'm leaving of the file suffix for this answer to help with clarity.)

The '/' character in the object-key has no special meaning in the guts of s3, it is just a character in the object-key.  However when other tools (including the AWS console web page) see objects with this character in the object-key they post process the s3 information to display / utilize this as a virtual folder.  This character has special meaning for many other tools and for us humans.

When you perform an UNLOAD, Redshift writes files to s3 giving them unique object-keys.  Every UNLOAD has the potential to write multiple files to S3. Since the max file size for an unload is 5GB, even with PARALLEL OFF the UNLOAD command may have to make more than 1 file.  This is why you are seeing "000" as this is the file number and it would be 001 if there is more than 5GB needed to be stored.  These are the "part"s of the output.

A PARALLEL ON, non-partitioned UNLOAD will make files with the provided base of the object-key and appending the slice number, "*part*" and the file part.  Like this `<object-path>/<name-prefix><slice-number>_part_<part-number>`.  This is one unique string per file stored in S3.

With PARALLEL OFF and non-partitiioned this string changes to `<object_path>/<name_prefix><part-number>`

And with PARALLEL OFF and partitioned this changes to `<object_path>/<name_prefix>/<partition>=<partition_value>/<part-number>`. The addition of the '/' characters to make the output compatible with other data tools (like HIVE) that need this virtual folder construct in S3 for partitioned data.  Even Redshift Spectrum uses this naming convention for partitioned data stored in S3.

The short answer to your question is 'no' you cannot change the file part portion of the resulting object using Redshift UNLOAD.

Understanding what you are trying to achieve by repeating the partition value in the file-part portion of the object-key would lead to more fruitful outcomes.